# Proper syntax of parameters using function run_in_executor()

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-requests, python-asyncio

To make a POST call to the API, I use the following script:

```
r = requests.post(
    url,
    headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    json={
        "email": my_email,
        "password": my_password
    }
)
```

and everything works. Now, I want to rewrite this code as a parameter to the function `run_in_executor()`. I did it in the following way but didn't get the desired results:

```
data1 = dict(
    headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    json={
        "email": my_email,
        "password": my_password
    }
)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future1 = loop.run_in_executor(
        None,
        requests.post,
        url,
        data1
    )
    # rest of the code
```

In fact, I get an error that tells me that it is mandatory to enter email and password, so obviously I am doing something wrong in passing the parameters. Printing `response = await future1` I get error 422. Can anyone help me?

Comment: First thing, you're mixing async code with synchronous code. `requests` library isn't using asyncio functionality, is pure synchronous library.

Comment: I had considered an example found online, so how should I change my code?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=run_in_executor#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) does not support keyword arguments.

You may use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools#functools.partial) to pack all arguments into one callable and pass it to `run_in_executor`.

```py
from functools import partial

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future1 = loop.run_in_executor(
        None,
        partial(
            requests.post,
            url,
            headers={
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            json={
                "email": my_email,
                "password": my_password
            }
        ),
    )
```